# How do you differentiate $f(x_1,x_2,...,x_n)=(f_1(x_1,x_2,...,x_n), f_2(x_1,x_2,...,x_n), ..., f_n(x_1,x_2,...,x_n))$?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives

How do you differentiate $$f(x_1,x_2,...,x_n)=(f_1(x_1,x_2,...,x_n), f_2(x_1,x_2,...,x_n), ..., f_n(x_1,x_2,...,x_n))$$?

Is it by taking the derivative of each of the component functions and then

$$f'(x_1,x_2,...,x_n)=(f_1'(x_1,x_2,...,x_n), f_2'(x_1,x_2,...,x_n), ..., f_n'(x_1,x_2,...,x_n))$$

?

How do you apply the chain rule to such vector?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a function $f:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}^n$ and functions $f_i:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}$.

Generally, the derivative of a function $f:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}^m$ at a point $a$ is, when it exists, a linear application $L:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}^m$ such that $\frac{\|r(h)\|}{\|h\|}\to0\quad(h\to0)$, where $f(a+h)=f(a)+L(h)+r(h)$. Then, there is a matrix $A\in M_{m\times n}$ such that $L(h)=Ah$ and we write $f'(a):=L$ (seen as a function) or $f'(a):=A$ (seen as a matrix associated with $L$).

Hence, the derivative of $f$ is an $n\times n$ matrix and the derivatives of the $f_i$ are $1\times n$ matrices.

A theorem says that if the derivative of $f$ exists at $a$, then the [jacobian matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobian_matrix_and_determinant) $J_f(a)$ of $f$ at $a$ exists and $f'(a)=J_f(a)$ (the converse is *false*).

All in all, what you wrote is incorrect but would be correct if you put it like this:
$$
f'(x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n)=\begin{pmatrix}f_1'(x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n)\\f_2'(x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n)\\\cdots\\f_n'(x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n)\end{pmatrix},
$$
each $f'_i$ representing rows in the matrix.

Answer (score 1):

I presume the functions $f_i,f$ all map from $\mathbb{R}^n$ into $\mathbb{R}$. In this case you can either consider the partial derivatives with respect to a given variable $\partial_if$, or compute the total derivative $Df$. In the first case the formula is given by the chain rule:
$$\partial_i f=\sum_{j=1}^n\partial_{f_j}f\cdot \partial_i f_j.$$
In the second $Df$ is just an $1\times n$ vector containing all partial derivatives calculated just as previously shown, i.e
$$Df=(\partial_1f,\ldots,\partial_nf)$$

Comment: What if they map to higher dimensions $\mathbb{R}^n$?

Comment: Then the result is the same, but you have to do everything component-wise. For more info go to the Wikipedia page "chain rule"

Comment: So every component gets its own $Df$?

Comment: Loosely speaking, yes. Basically the $Df$ (also called Jacobi Matrix, Differential, or Total Derivative when you look it up) is not an $1\times n$ matrix but can in general become an $m\times n $ matrix.